# Loading multiple keras models in django

Tags: django, keras

I have 5 trained keras models with their weights saved.
To get predictions, I first create the model with same architecture and then load the saved weights.

Now, I wanna get predictions from all these models in django and return them as json response.
Where should I load the models so that they are loaded only when the server starts?

Answer (score 0):

The answer depends on the type of data you are using, for example if it is Image classification task:

- You need first to load your images using a simple HTML/js form
- After
  receiving the images, you need to pre-process them like you did when
  you were trying to train your model.  meaning: if the model expects
  images on 224x224x3 input shape, the uploaded image need to be in
  that shape, then convert the image into a numpy array `img_to_array`
- Lastly, you need to pass this `img_to_array`   to model.predict()
  and get your results.

There are multiple blogs doing exactly this [example](https://medium.com/@chamakhabdallah8/how-to-deploy-a-keras-model-to-production-with-django-drf-celery-and-redis-df4901014355)